# Multiple datasources in war: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Tags: jpa, jdbc, transactions, ejb, persistence

Environment:

- Wildfly 10
- Java 8

I have a war project with a persistence unit(OracleDS) that access to a ejb.jar with another persistence unit(MySqlDS).

The server has configured both datasources as Non-XA.

The default transaction management is type Container, but if I use Transaction ManagementType.BEAN at class level it seems to work.

Why is that working? WHat is the difference with the Container type?

**Code in @Stateless class**

```
public void test() {
    Espacio espacioBase = espacioMgr.findByCodEspai(1); //EJB with 1st datasource

    Servei servei = ServeiMgr.findById(1); //EJB with 2nd datasource ERROR
}
```

**Espacio.java new.war**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "V_ESPACIOS")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Espacio.findByCodEspai, query = "SELECT e FROM Espacio e WHERE e.codespai = :codespai")})
public class Espacio implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String findByTipus = "Espacio.findByTipus";
    public static final String findByCodEspaiPare = "Espacio.findByCodEspaiPare";
    public static final String findByNom = "Espacio.findByNom";
    public static final String findAll = "Espacio.findAll";
    public static final String findByCodEspai = "Espacio.findByCodEspai";
    public static final String findChildrenByCodEspai = "Espacio.findChildrenByCodEspai";
...
```

**Servei.java ejb.jar**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a_servei")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Servei.findAll, query = "SELECT s FROM Servei s")})
    public class Servei implements Serializable, Comparable<Servei> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1979740551238968079L;

    static final String PREFIX = "pia.entity.Servei.";
    public static final String findAll = PREFIX + "findAll";
...
```

**ServeiManager**

```
@Stateless
public class ServeiManager {

    protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "onePU")
    protected EntityManager em;

    public List<Servei> all() {
        return this.em.createNamedQuery(Servei.findAll, Servei.class).
                getResultList();
    }
...
```

**EspacioManager**

```
@Stateless
public class EspacioManager {

    protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "twoPU")
    protected EntityManager em;

    public Espacio findByCodEspai(int codEspai) {
        return this.em.createNamedQuery(Espacio.findByCodEspai, Espacio.class).
                setParameter("codespai", codEspai).
                getSingleResult();
    }
...
```

**persistence.xml new.war**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="twoPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/jboss/datasources/OracleDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**persistence.xml ejb.jar**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="onePU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Error**

```
09:24:46,961 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (default task-18) ARJUNA012140: Adding multiple last resources is disallowed. Trying to add LastResourceRecord(XAOnePhaseResource(LocalXAResourceImpl@425d04d5[connectionListener=1949f99c connectionManager=76ebb8c8 warned=false currentXid=< formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffff7f000101:2b71c2d2:5a701dd6:13d, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff7f000101:2b71c2d2:5a701dd6:143, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS > productName=MySQL productVersion=5.5.44-MariaDB-log jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS])), but already have LastResourceRecord(XAOnePhaseResource(LocalXAResourceImpl@47bca654[connectionListener=2b07cb93 connectionManager=214b627a warned=false currentXid=< formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffff7f000101:2b71c2d2:5a701dd6:13d, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff7f000101:2b71c2d2:5a701dd6:141, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:jboss/datasources/OracleDS > productName=Oracle productVersion=Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Automatic Storage Management option jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/OracleDS]))
09:24:46,966 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-18) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
09:24:46,967 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-18) javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@1949f99c[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@33011f78 connection handles=0 lastReturned=1517300686965 lastValidated=1517297117411 lastCheckedOut=1517300686959 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@35406018 mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@2e374d12[pool=MySqlDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@425d04d5[connectionListener=1949f99c connectionManager=76ebb8c8 warned=false currentXid=null productName=MySQL productVersion=5.5.44-MariaDB-log jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS] txSync=null]
09:24:46,970 INFO  [org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener] (default task-18) HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
09:24:47,057 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-18) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component ServeiManager for method public es.imas.ada.business.gestio.entity.Servei es.imas.ada.business.gestio.boundary.ServeiManager.findById(int): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    ... more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    ... more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    ... more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@1949f99c[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@33011f78 connection handles=0 lastReturned=1517300686965 lastValidated=1517297117411 lastCheckedOut=1517300686959 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@35406018 mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@2e374d12[pool=MySqlDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@425d04d5[connectionListener=1949f99c connectionManager=76ebb8c8 warned=false currentXid=null productName=MySQL productVersion=5.5.44-MariaDB-log jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS] txSync=null]
    ... 240 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@1949f99c[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@33011f78 connection handles=0 lastReturned=1517300686965 lastValidated=1517297117411 lastCheckedOut=1517300686959 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@35406018 mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@2e374d12[pool=MySqlDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@425d04d5[connectionListener=1949f99c connectionManager=76ebb8c8 warned=false currentXid=null productName=MySQL productVersion=5.5.44-MariaDB-log jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS] txSync=null]
    ... 244 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000461: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object
    ... 246 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.SystemException: IJ000356: Failed to enlist: java.lang.Throwable: Unabled to enlist resource, see the previous warnings. tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff7f000101:2b71c2d2:5a701dd6:13d status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >
    ... 247 more
```

Comment: Please attach source code of classes Espacio, Servei and persistence.xml in your project and in ejb.jar. And describe how initialised EntityManager in both classes.

Comment: Is there a reason why your persistence context name is `onePU` and `twoPU` in your Stateless beans and the names in persistence.xml are `kronosPU` and `adaPU`?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to replace it before I posted it. Sorry!

Comment: Hey @Joe ,did you solve this problem?